# Python PWManager problem with TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python

Im getting the following error after entering a password:

This problem happened after adding the password function.
If i run the code without the password function it will encrypt and store

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

The program supposed to encrypt the password and store it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

```
import re
def encrypt(data, shift):
    encrypted = ""
    for i in range(len(data)):

        char = data[i]
        if (char.isupper()):
            encrypted += chr((ord(char) + shift - 65 % 26 + 65))

        elif (char.islower()):
            encrypted += chr((ord(char) + shift - 97) % 26 + 97)
        elif (char.isdigit()):
            number = (int(char) + shift) % 10
            encrypted += str(number)
        else:
            encrypted += char
    return encrypted





def password_check(password):
    numerics = '0123456789'
    capital_alphabets = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    lowercase_alphabet = 'abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    special_chars = '#?,!'

    sum = 0;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
    h = 0
    while sum != 4:
        while len(password) < 10:
            password = input('\nPlease Enter a Correct Password rakam')
        for i in range(len(password)):
            if password[i] in numerics:
                x = 1
            elif password[i] in capital_alphabets:
                y = 1
            elif password[i] in special_chars:
                z = 1
            elif re.search("MIT", password):
                h = 1

        sum = x + y + z + h
        if sum != 4:
            password = input('\nThe Password Must Meet the following CarteriaPlease enter a correct password')
        else:
            print('\nPassword is accepted')



menue = ""

while menue != '1' or menue != '2':
    menue = input("would you like to save a new password or view old ones"
                  "\n1. inputnew password"
                  "\n2. view passwords"
                  "\n3. exit")
    if menue == '1':
        accountname = input("Enter the name of your account")
        password = password_check(input("Enter you Password"))
        shift = 5
        file = open("Savedpasswords.txt", "a")
        file.write(encrypt(accountname,shift)+";|"+encrypt(password,shift)+"\n")
        file.close()

    if menue == '2':
        file = open("Savedpasswords.txt", "r")
        print("accountname\tpassword")
        for i in file:
            data = i.split(";|")
            print(data)

    if menue == '3':
        exit()
```

```
Password is accepted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hamzaabutaleb/PycharmProjects/PasswordManager/Main.py", line 66, in <module>
    file.write(encrypt(accountname,shift)+";|"+encrypt(password,shift)+"\n")
  File "/Users/hamzaabutaleb/PycharmProjects/PasswordManager/Main.py", line 4, in encrypt
    for i in range(len(data)):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to include the stack

Comment: Password is accepted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hamzaabutaleb/PycharmProjects/PasswordManager/Main.py", line 67, in <module>
    file.write(encrypt(accountname,shift)+";|"+encrypt(password,shift)+"\n")
  File "/Users/hamzaabutaleb/PycharmProjects/PasswordManager/Main.py", line 4, in encrypt
    for i in range(data):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: The error message does not contain the same code as the code you've added. Neither is the error message the same as what you've typed in your question's title. Please make sure that you have the correct code added and the correct error message; in this case it seems you're sending a string, the data to encrypt, as the argument directly to `range`.

Comment: Sorry, i have updated my post with the correct error

Comment: `Password is accepted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hamzaabutaleb/PycharmProjects/PasswordManager/Main.py", line 66, in <module>
    file.write(encrypt(accountname,shift)+";|"+encrypt(password,shift)+"\n")
  File "/Users/hamzaabutaleb/PycharmProjects/PasswordManager/Main.py", line 4, in encrypt
    for i in range(len(data)):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Process finished with exit code 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
password = password_check(input("Enter you Password"))
```

Since `password_check` doesn't explicitly return anything, it implicitly returns `None`, so this has the effect of setting `password` to `None`.  To fix it change it to:

```
password = input("Enter you Password")
password_check(password)
```

But if you want `password_check` to be able to prompt for a new password, then you should change it to return the password, in which case you would go back to assigning the result of `password_check` to `password`.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I have changed it to Password_check, however i have new error not since password is not defined anymore                                                                               'Password is accepted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hamzaabutaleb/PycharmProjects/PasswordManager/Main.py", line 65, in <module>
    file.write(encrypt(accountname,shift)+";|"+encrypt(password,shift)+"\n")
NameError: name 'password' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1'

Comment: `Password is accepted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hamzaabutaleb/PycharmProjects/PasswordManager/Main.py", line 65, in <module>
    file.write(encrypt(accountname,shift)+";|"+encrypt(password,shift)+"\n")
NameError: name 'password' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty in posting my answer.  Please refresh the page to pick up my updated answer.  You need to assign to `password` before calling `check_password`.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I have returned password in password_check. I really appreciate your help

Comment: By the way, note that if you want the user to be able to enter a new password in `password_check`, then you may need to change it to return the password, in which case you would go back to the original way you called it.